# Numerical Approximation - $\Sigma\to\int$

Tags: approximation, numerical-calculus

A function $f:\mathbb{Z}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is
$$f_L(n)=\frac{1}{1+b\frac{n}{L}-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{n}{L}\big)^2}$$
where integer $n\in [0,L]$ s.t., $\rho=n/L\in [0,1]$. We want to evaluate the product
$$P_L(j)=\prod\limits_{k<j}\bigg(1-\frac{f_L(n^*)}{f_L(k)}\bigg)$$
where $f_L(n^*)\le f_L(m)\forall m\in [0,L]$. We are interested in large $L$ limit.

**An approach**

My approach to evaluate $P_L(j)$: we can take $\log$ on both sides. The sum becomes integral in continuum limit (Remember large $L$). And we evaluate $P_L(j)$ as
$$P_L(j)=\exp\bigg(c\int\limits_0^{\rho_j}\log\big(1-\frac{f_L(n^*)}{f_L(k)}\big) \bigg)\Theta(n^*-j)$$
As $f(n^*)$ is constant inside the integral, so solving the integral is not big deal. I hope problem is well stated uptill here. If not please tell in comments below. Jumping to the question:

**Question:**

- What should be $c$?
- Or, I am completely wrong with my approach so we there is no $c$ in the first place!

Comment: Shouldn't $c=L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instead

$$f(x)=\frac1{1+bx-\frac12x^2}$$

so that $f_L(n)=f(n/L)$ and $f_L(n^\star)\simeq\min\limits_{0\le x\le1}f(x)=M$ is the minimum. Note that if the denominator has no roots in $[0,1]$, then the minimum is either $f(0)$ or $f(1)$ depending on the sign of $b$.

Let $x_k=k/L$. We are essentially interested in

$$\prod_{k<j}\left(1-\frac M{f(x_k)}\right)=\exp\sum_{k<j}\ln\left(1-\frac M{f(x_k)}\right)$$

which is not a Riemann sum. Consider instead

$$\frac1L\sum_{k<j}\ln\left(1-\frac M{f(x_k)}\right)\underset{L\to\infty}\longrightarrow\int_0^{j/L}\ln\left(1-\frac M{f(x)}\right)~\mathrm dx$$

so that it converges to the integral $I_j$. We then have the asymptotic behavior given by

$$\exp\sum_{k<j}\ln\left(1-\frac M{f(x_k)}\right)\simeq\exp(I_jL)$$

as $L\to\infty$.